# Unable to handle response in iFrame after backpress

Tags: node.js, reactjs, iframe, back-button

**Hello Guys**

I have some **third party content** displayed inside an **iFrame.**

**Problem :**

After clicking a component inside it when I **back press** to load my previous state I get below **response**.

```
{"response":"\"<!-- \\n   *************************************************\\n    Lorem Ipsum 
is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the 
industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of 
type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, 
but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was 
popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, 
and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of 
Lorem Ipsum.\\n   
**************************************************\\n -->\\n\\n<!doctype html>\\n<html 
lang=\\\"en\\\">\\n\\n<head>\\n  <meta charset=\\\"utf-8\\\">\\n  
<title>Abcd</title>\\n\\n   <!-- <base href=\\\"/\\\"> -->\\n\\n  <meta 
name=\\\"view\\\" content=\\\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1\\\">\\n  <link 
rel=\\\"icon\\\" type=\\\"image/ds-icon\\\" href=\\\"favicon.ico\\\">\\n<link 
rel=\\\"stylesheet\\\" href=\\\"styles.asasa.css\\\"></head>\\n\\n<body>\\n  
<app-root>\\n    <div id=\\\"loader\\\">\\n      <style>\\n        .app-load- 
cont {\\n          display: flex;\\n          flex-direction: column;\\n          
justify-content: center;\\n          align-items: center;\\n          height: 100vh;\\n        
}\\n\\n        .app-load-box {\\n          width: 300px;\\n          margin: 
5px;\\n          text-align: center;\\n        }\\n\\n        .lds-roll {\\n          
display: inline-block;\\n          position: relative;\\n          width: 80px;\\n          
height: 80px;\\n        }\\n\\n        .lds-roll div {\\n          animation: lds-roll 
1.2s cubic-bezier(0.5, 0, 0.5, 1) infinite;\\n          transform-origin: 40px 40px;\\n        
}\\n\\n        .lds-roll div:after {\\n          content: \\\" \\\";\\n          display: 
block;\\n          position: absolute;\\n          width: 7px;\\n          height: 7px;\\n          
border-radius: 50%;\\n          background: #007D62;\\n          margin: -4px 0 0 -4px;\\n        
}\\n\\n        .lds-roll div:nth-child(1) {\\n          animation-delay: -0.036s;\\n        
}\\n\\n        .lds-roll div:nth-child(1):after {\\n          top: 63px;\\n          left: 
63px;\\n        }\\n\\n        .lds-roll div:nth-child(2) {\\n          animation-delay: 
-0.072s;\\n        }\\n\\n        .lds-roll div:nth-child(2):after {\\n          top: 
68px;\\n          left: 56px;\\n        }\\n\\n        .lds-roll div:nth-child(3) {\\n          
animation-delay: -0.108s;\\n        }\\n\\n        .lds-roll div:nth-child(3):after {\\n          
top: 71px;\\n          left: 48px;\\n        }\\n\\n        .lds-roll div:nth-child(4) {\\n          
animation-delay: -0.144s;\\n        }\\n\\n        .lds-roll div:nth-child(4):after {\\n          
top: 72px;\\n          left: 40px;\\n        }\\n\\n        .lds-roll div:nth-child(5) {\\n          
animation-delay: -0.18s;\\n        }\\n\\n        .lds-roll div:nth-child(5):after {\\n          
top: 71px;\\n          left: 32px;\\n        }\\n\\n        .lds-roll div:nth-child(6) {\\n          
animation-delay: -0.416s;\\n        }\\n\\n        .lds-roll div:nth-child(6):after {\\n          
top: 68px;\\n          left: 24px;\\n        }\\n\\n        .lds-roll div:nth-child(7) {\\n          
animation-delay: -0.452s;\\n        }\\n\\n        .lds-roll div:nth-child(7):after {\\n          
top: 63px;\\n          left: 17px;\\n        }\\n\\n        .lds-roll div:nth-child(8) {\\n          
animation-delay: -0.488s;\\n        }\\n\\n        .lds-roll div:nth-child(8):after {\\n          
top: 56px;\\n          left: 12px;\\n        }\\n\\n        @keyframes lds-roll {\\n             
0% {\\n            transform: rotate(0deg);\\n          }\\n\\n          100% {\\n            
transform: rotate(360deg);\\n          }\\n        }\\n      </style>\\n      <div 
class=\\\"appl-load-cont\\\">\\n        <div class=\\\"app-load- 
box\\\">\\n          <div class=\\\"lds-roll\\\">\\n            <div></div>\\n            
<div></div>\\n            <div></div>\\n            <div></div>\\n            <div></div>\\n            
<div></div>\\n            <div></div>\\n            <div></div>\\n          </div>\\n        
</div>\\n      </div>\\n    </div>\\n  </app-root>\\n<script  
src=\\\"run.werwe.js\\\" defer></script><script  
src=\\\"poly.564564.js\\\" defer></script><script 
src=\\\"sc.234234.js\\\" defer></script><script 
src=\\\"main.12133.js\\\" defer></script>
</body>\\n\\n</html>\"","valid":true}
```

But while inspecting the body tag I found that a **pre tag** is getting added instead of the **div tags.**

Also when I open the pre tag **manually** I can see above response **inside " "**.

[image]

Any help or suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean by state?

Comment: By state I mean the first web page of the third party component which was loaded after the API call of the above response. The same API is again called during back press so it was supposed to load the previous page but facing above issue.

Comment: I tried adding popstate event to handle that manually but when I back press the popstate   event is not called when the above response loads after second backpress the event is called.:(